# IsSuccessStatusCode is FALSE

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, asp.net-web-api

Please see the client side code below:

```
namespace ReleaseLearning.Controllers
{
    public class CreateEmployeeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /CreateEmployee/

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };

        string uri = "http://localhost:52929/";


        public ActionResult CreateEmployee()
        {
            //http://localhost:52929/CreateEmployee/CreateEmployee
            //Employee Objemployee = new Employee();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler); //It will not authenticate if you remove handler (authorize attribute on server side)

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Values").Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var EmployeeDetails = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Employee>>().Result;
            }
            //return View(objEmployee);
            return View();
        }
} }
```

and the server side code below:

```
[HttpGet]


         [Authorize]
            public List<Employee> GetemployeeList()
            {
                string username = System.Environment.UserName;

                List<Employee> Employee = new List<Employee>{
    new Employee{Employee_ID=123,Employee_Name="Saurabh Sri"},
    new Employee{Employee_ID=1567,Employee_Name="Samir Saxena"},
    };
                return Employee;
            }
```

I run this code in Visual Studio on a PC connected to the domain and it works as expected i.e. `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is true.  However, if I run it in Visual Studio on a PC connected to a workgroup (rather than a domain), then `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is false.  Why is it false?

Comment: Any authentication on the rest service?

Comment: Is `System.Environment.UserName` giving you the same results in both the cases?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, I am running this in Visual Studio 2013 and I have set Windows Authentication to: enabled in visual studio.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf , yes. It strips off the domain name and workgroup name.

Comment: @w0051977 Try `System.Environment.UserDomainName` this thing and check whether you get the same result in both the cases.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, userdomainname is the PC name for a local user and the domain name for a domain user.]

Comment: Try setting the Authentication to Anonymous on your rest service.  If it works then, you know the issue is Authentication.    Probably because you can't use Windows Authentication if you aren't part of the same domain.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, I have already tried that.  The only thing that has changed is that it is a local user.  Same code.

Comment: Did it work when you tried?   How do you expect a local user to authenticate using windows authentication?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, it did not work when I tried.  The client and service are installed on the same development PC i.e. one Visual studio solution with two projects.  Does Windows auth only work with domains i.e. not workgroups?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf,, with WCF, I believe you can authenticate as a local user.  I thought this would be the same with web-api.

Comment: No Windows Auth does not work in a Workgroup.   Yes you can use a local user to authenticate, but for that you have to use Basic Authentication

Comment: @ Dijkgraaf, thanks.  If you post an answer to that effect then I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connecting from a machine not in Domain (e.g.in a Workgroup) your caller/API can't use Windows Authentication.

You have to change your caller & API to use another authentication method.  In the case of a local user setup on the IIS server you need to use Basic Authentication.